# getResource puts a leading / before the disk name using java 1.7 windows 7

Tags: java, getresource

The following gives a leading slash before the disk name.
How can I avoid that?

```
String pngpath = getClass().getResource("/resources/image.png").getPath();
System.out.println("pngpath = "+pngpath);
```

Gives:

```
pngpath = /C:/Users/jgrimsdale/Documents/NetBeansProjects/HelloCV/build/classes/resources/image.png
```

Comment: What happens when you remove the leading slash from your `getResource` statement?

Comment: I believe that path is still valid, even with the leading `/`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Not in certain contexts it isn't.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Apparently not in Java NIO's getPath() http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834776/java-nio-file-path-issue

Answer (score 36):

Use:

```
String pngpath = getClass().getResource("/resources/image.png").getFile();
File file = new File(pngpath);
System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

Answer (score 2):

A constructor of File(uri) or File(string) helps to get file object from system dependent path string or URI object.

It is a solution to using the Java Library.

```
System.out.println(new File("/C:/Users/jgrimsdale").toString())
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File(java.net.URI)

Answer (score -1):

you can do this using this code.

```
System.out.println("pngpath = "+pngpath.substring(1,pngpath.length()));
```

Comment: this would yield a filenotfound on linux where the leading slash is necessary. @diogosantana 's answer is more platform independant