# Java NIO move file to a shared location

Tags: java, nio

In my case i need to copy a file from local folder to shared location.

```
Files.copy(new File("C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\Tulips.jpg").toPath(), new File("\\\10.101.1.2\\resources\\Files\\exbury\\Tulips.jpg").toPath(),
                    java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

> java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <> at index 1:
>   \.101.1.2\ZoneResources\File Share\burusoth\Tulips.jpg   at
>   sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(WindowsPathParser.java:182)    at
>   sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:153)    at
>   sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:77)     at
>   sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(WindowsPath.java:94)     at
>   sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(WindowsFileSystem.java:255)  at
>   java.io.File.toPath(File.java:2234)   at
>   com.zone.qv2.s2c.resultupload.TestClass.method(TestClass.java:31)     at
>   com.zone.qv2.s2c.resultupload.TestClass.main(TestClass.java:22)

It means NIO doesn't allow `slashes \` in front of a path as said in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834776/java-nio-file-path-issue). In my case i have to specify shared location as url which starts with `slashes`. How can i overcome this issue?

Is there are any ways to copy files from local location to shared location?

Comment: Instead of `"\\\"` try `"\\\\"` which is the same as `\\` after escaping.  Do you really have to use DOS path separators?

Comment: other way to 'fix' this would be to bind the network location to a 'windows drive'.   http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/49517-map-network-drive.html

Comment: @Peter thank you. simple escaping error made me mad.

Comment: @Peter is there any other way than using DOS path seperator.

Comment: You can use `/` as URLs do.  This doesn't mean it will automount UNC paths, you you can use `/` instead of `\\`.

Answer (score 3):

The Java String value you are using for your UNC path is:

> \\\10.101.1.2\\resources\\Files\\exbury\\Tulips.jpg

A UNC path normally takes the form of:

```
\\10.101.1.2\resources\Files\exbury\Tulips.jpg
```

Each slash `\` must be escaped as `\\` in a Java String.

The Java String value of the resulting path should be:

> \\\\10.101.1.2\\resources\\Files\\exbury\\Tulips.jpg

**You are missing a preceding `\` character.**

Using `/` also works and does not need to be escaped; the Java String value using `/` is:

> //10.101.1.2/resources/Files/exbury/Tulips.jpg