# How do I write/read/delete contents of a text file located in my resources folder?

Tags: java, text-files, editing

I have a text file in my resource folder and I need to be able to read/remove/add text. I believe I have to use append so I tried this.

```
Files.write(Paths.get(Testing.class.getResource("/testresources/SearchList.txt").getPath())
, "the text".getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
```

This gives me back

`Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 2: /C:/Users/Ben/workspace/Eve/bin/org/me/Testing/resources/SearchList.txt`

If anyone could should me some clarity on this subject that would be great. Thankyou!

Comment: Looks like it's complaining about the `C:/` what type of OS are you on?  Windows?

Comment: ya.  I think you should be fine if that path resolved to `/Users/Ben/workspace/Eve/bin/org/me/Testing/resources/SearchList.txt` without the `C:/`

Comment: The program is going to be made into a jar file and run on multiple machines, will it still work then if its like that

Comment: Oh yup!  Definitely want it to be generic.  Just suggesting trying to find a method that generically returns something without the `C:/`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me fine:

You should add the text file to a raw folder. If the raw folder does not exist in your resource directory, create one. And then in order to access it and write or edit it, use this:

```
OutputStream outputStream=getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.YourTextFile);
```

then in order to Read from the file, you should do this

```
InputStream inputStream=getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.YourTextFile);
```

Comment: How do you create a raw folder? I'm using eclipse.

Comment: I have not used eclipse for a long time but i think when you right click on the resources folder it should give an option to do that

Answer (score 0):

A leading slash is being automatically added to your path - **/C:/Users/Ben/workspace/Eve/bin/org/me/Testing/resources/SearchList.txt**

Lots of solutions have been suggested here in answers, [Java NIO file path issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834776/java-nio-file-path-issue)

Use any of those mentioned answers as your solution.

Also, for files intended to be in jar, You need to use `Paths` method `public static Path get(URI uri)` instead of `public static Path get(String first,String... more)` See [How to get a path to a resource in a Java JAR file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941754/how-to-get-a-path-to-a-resource-in-a-java-jar-file)

Comment: I'm going to be making this a jar file and using it on multiple machines, I don' think having the direct route to the folder will work then.

Comment: I have edited my answer, you need to use uri if file is intended to reside in jar