# Cut off URIs with respect to another

Tags: java, uri

We have `resolve` which transforms `a/b` + `c/d` to `a/b/c/d`.

We have `relativize` which transforms `a/b` + `a/b/c/d` to `c/d`.

Is there a way to transform `a/b/c/d` + `c/d` to `a/b`?

---

For my special problem (classpaths) the URIs are not convertible to `java.nio.file.Path`s, with the error

```
java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 3: jar:file:/D:/devel/somejar.jar!/foo/Bar.class
```

I want to resolve the directory of an entry (for example given `Bar.class`) and the `URI` as yielded by `getClassLoader().getResource().toURI()` to `jar:file:/D:/devel/somejar.jar!/foo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `java.nio.file.Path` but you'd have to use a custom file system since the URI scheme here is `jar` not `file`. [This page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemprovider.html) shows an example.

```
URI uri = URI.create("jar:file:/D:/devel/somejar.jar!/foo/Bar.class");

String[] array = uri.toString().split("!");
String jarFile = array[0];
String entryPath = array[1];
try(FileSystem fs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(URI.create(jarFile), new HashMap<>())) {
    Path path = fs.getPath(entryPath);
    URI parentUri = path.getParent().toUri();
    ...
}
```

Or the easy way using a substring:

```
URI uri = URI.create("jar:file:/D:/devel/somejar.jar!/foo/Bar.class");
URI parent = URI.create(uri.toString().substring(0, uri.toString().lastIndexOf("/")));
```

Comment: This approach requires that the classloader returns a `jar:` path. Any way to make the first part (`toString.split()`) more general?

Comment: What are the possible types of URIs that can be returned by the classloader? If the resource is always on the filesystem, i.e. either a class file or inside a Jar, then `java.nio.file.Path` and `java.io.File` should be more than enough to get parent paths.

Comment: I'm not quite sure that everything is on the filesystem, but when you put it that way, I think it is enough. I won't accept the answer yet, as the more general question hasn't been sufficently answer though (when `c` is a complete path, I'll make that more clear)

Answer (score 1):

```
URI uri = Main.class.getClassLoader().getResource("java/net/URISyntaxException.class").toURI();
//URI uri = URI.create("jar:file:/D:/devel/somejar.jar!/foo/Bar.class");
System.out.println(uri.toString());
System.out.println(Paths.get(uri.toString()).getParent());
```

jar:file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar!/java/net/URISyntaxException.class
jar:file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar!/java/net

toString is the trick

Comment: I get `Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 3: jar:file:/D:/bin/Java/jdk8u65/jre/lib/rt.jar!/java/net/URISyntaxException.class` at line 4.

Comment: Ah! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834776/java-nio-file-path-issue Windows vs Linux saga continues :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you want to achieve. You can simply remove the end portion of the path using regex. I have used the String.class as an example.

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
    // get URI of class
    String clazz = "String.class";

    URI resourceURI = String.class.getResource(clazz).toURI();
    System.out.println(resourceURI);
    System.out.println(resourceURI.toString().replaceAll("^(.+?)!?/?" + clazz + "$", "$1"));

    clazz = "/lang/String.class";
    System.out.println(resourceURI.toString().replaceAll("^(.+?)!?/?" + clazz + "$", "$1"));

    clazz = "java/lang/String.class";
    System.out.println(resourceURI.toString().replaceAll("^(.+?)!?/?" + clazz +  "$", "$1"));
}
```

If you want to try and load the data into a Path then you can do the following:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
    // get URI of class
    String clazz = "String.class";

    URI resourceURI = String.class.getResource(clazz).toURI();
    System.out.println(resourceURI.getScheme());
    System.out.println(resourceURI.getRawSchemeSpecificPart());
    URI fileURI = new URI(resourceURI.getRawSchemeSpecificPart());
    System.out.println(fileURI.getScheme());
    System.out.println(fileURI.getRawSchemeSpecificPart());
    Path path = Paths.get(fileURI);
    System.out.println(path);
    System.out.println(path.getParent());
}
```